how to create a bulletpoint in AWS Lex using AWS Lambda as backend
I am working on an AWS Lex chatbot and using an AWS Lambda function as the backend to generate responses. My goal is to display a response with bullet points in Lex.
The desired format should looks like this:
Here are the details of your order: 
• Order ID: 12345 
• Created on: 2024-12-31 

However, the actual response displayed in Lex appears as a single paragraph without proper formatting:
Here are the details of your order: • Order ID: 12345 • Created on: 2024-12-31

What I Have Tried

Using Newline Characters (\n): I attempted to add new lines between each bullet point, but Lex seems to ignore them.

Using HTML: I tried <br> and <ul><li> tags, but they were displayed as plain text rather than rendering the expected formatting.

Markdown Syntax: Using * or - for bullets also resulted in unformatted text.


Code Example
Here’s the Lambda function I am using:
'messages': [ 
    { "contentType": "PlainText", 
      "content": "f"Here are the details of your order:\n• Order ID: {row['orderId']}\n• Created on: {row['Date']}"
    } 
] 

Expected vs. Actual Behavior

Expected: The response in Lex should display with bullet points and proper formatting as shown in the first example.

Actual: The response is rendered as a single paragraph without line breaks or bullet points.


Additional Context

AWS Lex Version: V2.

ContentType: I am using "PlainText, responsecardtype" for the response message.

Frontend Behavior: The issue persists across all frontend integrations Lex Web UI.


